# Store HTML tags in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form which contains a textarea for additional notes that user might want to add.
The tag for notes is as follows :

```
<label class="edit_label" for="notes">
 <a href="#" title="Provide additional details">Notes
   <span class="question">?</span>
 </a>
</label>
<textarea id="notes" name="notes" class="alert_conf">
  <?=htmlentities($data->alert->notes)?>
</textarea>
```

When I try to store this in the database, all the html tags are getting striped. I tried replace them with `&lt` and `&gt` but it doesn't work. I want to store the tags also in database. How to do that ? 
I am using the `quote()` function for the mysql query.

Comment: You should not use `htmlentities` before storing raw html tag in db. Use `htmlentities or htmlspecialchars` when outputting the html tags.

Comment: @moskito-x.de : I am wrapping all the fields to be inserted into the table in an array bu writing a function called get_vars_for_db. And after that for each value (bu running a foreach loop), i do the following     ***$value_array[] = quote($value, (empty($this->field_type[$sql_name])) ? WF_NUMERIC : $this->field_type[$sql_name]);***

Comment: I tried to insert into the database without using quote. I thought quote() might be stripping off the html tags. But of no success. I dont know what is going wrong where??

Comment: What have you got without using `quote()`? Provide your php code too so that we can understand how you are entering & retrieving data.

Comment: Without using quotes **if ($sql_name == 'AtNotes'){
        $params[] = $sql_name . " = '" . $value . "'";** But even till here, the value is coming is without the tags. I cannot understand at what part are the tags getting stripped. Before this am doing nothing but converting them into a array in another file.

Comment: If it helps, the function for converting in an array is as follows  ' public function get_vars_for_db($query_conf = []) {
    $vars = [
       'id' => $this->id,
       'name' => $this->name,
       'recipients' => implode(',', array_map('trim', $this->recipients)),
       'subject' => $this->subject,
       'notes' => $this->notes
    ];
    return $vars;'

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the function `mysqli_real_escape_string (mysqli $link, string $escapestr)` to remove any possible mysql special chars from the string. Also, make sure the data type in the database is `TEXT`, as the binary could be too large for whatever datatype it is you're using.

[documentation on mysqli_real_escape()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).